# Date being automatically converted in browser window

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I currently am experiencing a problem when printing a date on the frontend of a website I'm working on. The date is retrieved via Node.js (`mysql` module) from a a MySql db, where it's stored in a MySql `DATETIME` format. The view engine being used is Handlebars.

The problem consists in the date being automatically converted when in the browser window, and I'm currently out of luck with trying to figure out where and how this is happening. Console.logging the 'date' field retrieved from the node db query gives me a `2018-12-27T18:00:00.000Z` type of date, but in the browser this date is getting printed as `Thu Dec 27 2018 19:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)`. I already tried to do a `date = date.toString()` conversion on the Node side, but to no avail.

-

This is the code on the node.js side:

```
app.get( '/blog' , ( req , res ) => {
    db.get().query( `SELECT * FROM posts` , ( error , results ) => {
        res.render( "./blog.hbs" , 
            { 
                pageTitle : "xx - My Blog" ,
                posts     : results              
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me solve this puzzle.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is using the ISO DateTime format to store the timestamp, which is pretty standard and safe. Putting this timestamp inside the JS Date Constructor should not result in any type of conversions.

However, when the toString() method on the Date object is called, it usually generates the timestamp by taking the local machine's timezone offset into consideration. And the timezone is also added at the end of timestamp.

So from what I can guess, this is probably not an issue on your server side, rather you should check the code of the client application you're running in the browser.

If you want to output the exact same timestamp on the client side as the server side, then use the Date.toISOString() method.

Comment: Yep, thank you, an implicit conversion on the client side was what I was talking about indeed. Thank you for the heads up on the 'toString()'  details, too! The actual problem for me consists in details like Day and Month being outputted in natural language, but I'll try the `Date.toIsoString()` method and report back ASAP!

Comment: Glad I could help